# Query with a foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I mix a little bit with the query in laravel.

I have a list of articles. I would like to get the datas from the author of this article.

Relation model Article

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
}
```

Relation model Author

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
}
```

I try this `$author = Author::with('articles')->first();`

this :

```
$author = Author::whereHas('articles', function ($query){
        $query->where('id', '1');
    });
```

And many others tests, but I doesn't understand all.

My method in my controller :

```
protected function index()
{


    $articles = Article::published()->paginate(8);

    return view('pages.blog', [
        'articles' => $articles,
    ]);
}
```

And above all, how do I display the correct information in my view in my foreach?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you have to define the relationships in the following way.

Article class define, based on the following table structure:

```
articles {   
   id : integer [primary key],  
   ...,  
   author_id : integer [foreign key]  
}
```

```
class Article extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

  protected $table = "articles";      

  // HERE YOUR CLASS CODE

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo("Author", "author_id", "id");
  }
}
```

Author class define, based on the following table structure:

```
authors {   
   id : integer [primary key],  
   ...  
}
```

```
class Author extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

  protected $table = "authors";      

  // HERE YOUR CLASS CODE

  public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany("Article", "author_id", "id");
  }
}
```

When you use the method `belongsTo` and `hasMany`, it is better indicate the label of the external key and the local key.

To display information in your view you have to follow the example:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <p>Id {{ $article->id }}</p>
    ...
@endforeach
```

For more information :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade